# after Field Service upgrade, refreshMembershipStatusIcons is not defined

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

After upgrade from version `7.5.9.91` to version `8.8.11.19` I started to face following error when opening  Project entity `msdyn_project` on UCI:

```
ReferenceError: refreshMembershipStatusIcons is not defined
    at eval (eval at executeFunction (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1279:2768), <anonymous>:1:13)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at Nu.executeFunction (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1279:2768)
    at Nu.execute (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1279:2428)
    at iu (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1271:62)
    at https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1275:23166
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Cu._getEventHandlerList (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1275:22978)
    at Object.execute (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:1275:16253)
    at O._executeSyncAction (https://ORGNAME.crm.dynamics.com/uclient/scripts/app.js?v=1.4.831-2005.2:841:692)
```

Do you have any clue what might be wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We managed to find answer - one of forms on Project entity had duplicate registration for one of OOB js function handlers.
Please review all of your forms in given entity and verify that each function is registered only once.

Answer (score 0):

Go to form editor of project entity form, verify the form properties, there may be an event method registered in form load to trigger this `refreshMembershipStatusIcons` method from a particular library.

Probably this method/library has been retired or renamed, and dependency has not been removed properly. Try to remove that event handler and see. [Read more](https://reenhanced.com/2019/how-to-get-started-with-form-scripts-in-dynamics-365/)

Comment: actual solution was a little different - one of the forms had duplicate registration of one of js function handlers.

Comment: @Tomasz, interesting. you can add your answer to help someone.